# How to configure Debian 11 Desktop PC (computer with GUI) as a router (internet sharing)

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables, dnsmasq

I have two desktop machines, Windows 10 and Debian 11. These machines both have single 1G ethernet ports on the motherboards as well as an ASUS 10G PCI-e add in card.

I don't own a 10G switch to connect these machines, but I want to be able to setup a 10G connection between them for remote desktop useage.

There are several possible ways of approaching this problem

- Share an internet connection from Windows 10 to Debian 11
- Setup a static connection between the two machines, but retain the 1G connections for internet access (triangle configuration)
- Share an internet connection from Debian 11 to Windows 10

I tried the first two methods and failed. I don't know much about how Windows works, so I wasn't able to diagnose/figure out why the first method didn't work.

The second method I have attempted before but things didn't seem to work well and didn't seem to be very stable. It might work one week and not work the next. I never got to the bottom of why this happened.

I think I have the most chance of getting the last method to work. That is

```
Windows 10 -> Debian 11 -> Network
```

So far I have done the following things:

```
sudo apt install dnsmasq

vim /etc/dnsmasq.conf
interface=enp4s0
listen-address=127.0.0.1
dhcp-range=192.168.10.50,192.168.10.150,24h

vim /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

sudo apt install iptables-persistent
```

I did **not** change the contents of `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` because this came autoconfigured with some stuff:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Apr  9 11:27:33 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Apr  9 11:27:33 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Apr  9 11:27:33 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Apr  9 11:27:33 2022
```

The first issue I have is I don't know if I am missing some content from the iptables configuration. For reference, I was following this [guide](https://gridscale.io/en/community/tutorials/debian-router-gateway/).

- I am actually not sure if I even need to install iptables. It is a firewall "thing", however if I remember correctly I believe it is needed otherwise the default kernel behaviour is to "block everything not destined for the local machine" - and I think this continues to be true even if the kernel is set to forward ip packets with `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.

If I am mistaken about this or my information is out of date please correct me.

The second issue I have is I don't know how the setup might differ considering this is a Desktop machine with a GUI. (Xfce desktop environment.) This comes with Network Manager, from which adapters can be configured with static IP addresses. The above linked [guide](https://gridscale.io/en/community/tutorials/debian-router-gateway/) does not mention anything about setting a static IP for the adapter `enp4s0`, which is configured as the adapter dnsmasq will use to listen for DHCP requests.

However surely it would need a static IP to be configured, otherwise how would other machines be able to establish an ethernet connection to this interface?

In which case, I can configure a static IP with network manager, however I do not know in what way running Xfce desktop environment might interfere with other parts of the configuration. (Perhaps I am concerned about something which is a non-issue?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did two things to make this work, although regarding the second I do not understand why what I did works.

1. Set static IP configuration with Network Manager. No routes defined. Everything else default

[image: Network Manager]

2. This is my iptables rules.v4. (Comments and irrelevant docker lines removed)

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i enp4s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp4s0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

The main change which seemed to make this work was adding `-A INPUT -i enp4s0 -j ACCEPT`.

I have no idea why this worked. `enp4s0` is the interface of the 10G network adapter. This machine should not be accepting traffic on this interface, it should be *forwarding* it. (If connecting to this host directly, eg via remote desktop or ssh then I can understand why adding to the `INPUT` chain would make a difference, but I don't understand why adding to the `INPUT` chain makes any difference to the connected machines ability to ping `8.8.8.8`, for example.)

There must be something I don't understand regarding how `iptables` works. Please comment if you know the answer.